# How should I extract a subset from Cifar-100 as my customized training set?

Tags: python, dataset, image-classification

I hope to extract 10% of training samples from each class in Cifar-100 to build up a subset of original training set. I am using PyTorch.

I tried to do this on Cifar-10, the idea is to search for the serial numbers of samples in each class, collect 10% of them, and then extract samples that correspond to these collected serial numbers from the original dataset. The code is as following:

```
indices_airplane = []
indices_automobile = []
indices_bird = []
indices_cat = []
indices_deer = []
indices_dog = []
indices_frog = []
indices_horse = []
indices_ship = []
indices_truck = []

idx_airplane = trainset.class_to_idx['airplane']
idx_automobile = trainset.class_to_idx['automobile']
idx_bird = trainset.class_to_idx['bird']
idx_cat = trainset.class_to_idx['cat']
idx_deer = trainset.class_to_idx['deer']
idx_dog = trainset.class_to_idx['dog']
idx_frog = trainset.class_to_idx['frog']
idx_horse = trainset.class_to_idx['horse']
idx_ship = trainset.class_to_idx['ship']
idx_truck = trainset.class_to_idx['truck']

for i in range(len(trainset)):
    current_class = trainset[i][1]
    if current_class == idx_airplane:
        indices_airplane.append(i)
    elif current_class == idx_automobile:
        indices_automobile.append(i)
    elif current_class == idx_bird:
        indices_bird.append(i)
    elif current_class == idx_cat:
        indices_cat.append(i)
    elif current_class == idx_deer:
        indices_deer.append(i)
    elif current_class == idx_dog:
        indices_dog.append(i)
    elif current_class == idx_frog:
        indices_frog.append(i)
    elif current_class == idx_horse:
        indices_horse.append(i)
    elif current_class == idx_ship:
        indices_ship.append(i)
    elif current_class == idx_truck:
        indices_truck.append(i)

indices_airplane = indices_airplane[:int(0.1 * len(indices_airplane))]
indices_automobile = indices_automobile[:int(0.1 * len(indices_automobile))]
indices_bird = indices_bird[:int(0.1 * len(indices_bird))]
indices_cat = indices_cat[:int(0.1 * len(indices_cat))]
indices_deer = indices_deer[:int(0.1 * len(indices_deer))]
indices_dog = indices_dog[:int(0.1 * len(indices_dog))]
indices_frog = indices_frog[:int(0.1 * len(indices_frog))]
indices_horse = indices_horse[:int(0.1 * len(indices_horse))]
indices_ship = indices_ship[:int(0.1 * len(indices_ship))]
indices_truck = indices_truck[:int(0.1 * len(indices_truck))]

trainset = Subset(trainset, indices_airplane+indices_automobile+indices_bird+indices_cat+indices_deer+indices_dog+indices_frog+indices_horse+indices_ship+indices_truck)
```

which worked as intended. However in the case of using Cifar-100, this method might be dumb. I was wondering if there could be a more effective way of doing this data processing?

Comment: What do you mean *might* be dumb? What *exactly* is your issue?

Comment: I mean if I apply the same idea of processing Cifar-10 on Cifar-100, the amount of code will be ten times more than what I showed above, so I was trying to say it is not effective

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.